# Custom accessors Eloquent Model

Tags: arrays, laravel, model, eloquent

I have a Eloquent Model and I want to create a customized toArray method...

```
class Posts extends Model {

    public function scopeActives($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', '=', '1');
    }

    public function toCustomJS()
    {
        $array = parent::ToArray();
        $array['location'] = someFunction($this->attributes->location);

        return $array;
    }
}

//In my controller:

Posts::actives()->get()->toArray(); //this is working
Posts::actives()->get()->toCustomJS(); //Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::toCustomJS()
```

How can I override the toArray method or create another "export" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get()` actually returns a `Collection` object which contains 0, 1, or many models which you can iterate through so it's no wonder why adding these functions to your model are not working.  What you will need to do to get this working is to create your custom `Collection` class, override the `toArray()` function, and also override the function in your model responsible for building that collection so it can return the custom `Collection` object.

### CustomCollection class

```
class CustomCollection extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {

    protected $location;

    public function __construct(array $models = Array(), $location)
    {
        parent::__construct($models);
        $this->location = $location;
    }

    // Override the toArray method
    public function toArray($location = null)
    {
        $original_array = parent::toArray();

        if(!is_null($location)) {
            $original_array['location'] = someFunction($this->location);
        }

        return $original_array;
    }
}
```

### Overriding the newCollection method on your models

And for the models you wish to return `CustomCollection`

```
class YourModel extends Eloquent {

    // Override the newCollection method
    public function newCollection(array $models = Array())
    {
        return new \CustomCollection($models, $this->attributes['location']);
    }

}
```

Please note this may not be what you are intending.  Because a `Collection` is really just an array of models, it's not good to depend on the `location` attribute of a single model.  Depending on your use-case, it's something that can change from model to model.

It might also be a good idea to drop this method into a trait and then just use that trait in each model you wish to implement this feature in.

**Edit:**

If you don't want to go through creating a custom `Collection` class, you can always just do it manually each time...

```
$some_array = Posts::actives()->get()->toArray();
$some_array['location'] = someFunction(Posts::first()->location);
return Response::json($some_array);
```

Comment: Hmm thank you for your solution but that's now what I was expecting :/ I am looking a way to get all my rows on my models and export it in my way... You know something like Posts::actives()->toJSON() but in my personal format... Is it possible without passing via Collection? Because it look very complicated

Comment: I've modified my answer.